# Why no record locking in civicase?

Tags: civicase

I haven't tested all the parts of civicase, but so far I have found that updates to activities, the main case record and custom fields are not locked.

Two users can update the same information with no warning or error at all.

Is this correct or is there a config option I have missed?

V5.17.4 on Drupal 7 if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 3):

Regular activities are like that too. Locking isn't widely implemented. It's not on purpose just hasn't been implemented.

In the first few years of CiviCase's life it used to always make new copies when you edited an activity. You'd still have no warning if two people edit, but you'd see the previous versions. It wasn't a good technical design performance-wise and in fact you couldn't turn it off. Then a feature called advanced/detailed logging was added that logs changes to all tables in civi, but it's not turned on by default. Again there'd be no warning, but you'd have the history for all records. Then at some point the case activity revisions feature was converted into an optional feature and turned off by default too. Then it stopped working. So, at the moment, as a partial solution you can turn on detailed logging (under Administer - System Settings - Misc, where it's just called Logging). Then at least you'll have the record in the database (it creates another set of tables named log_civicrm_XXX).

Comment: WTF!     Seriously how is civicase used then?   That's insane putting out a system that has no data integrity.   How can any organisation use this?

Comment: The software is free and only has what it has because of contributions from the people using it. If you're able to submit patches (https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/core/contributing/) or an extension for this that would be great, or alternatively if you have funding available you can contact someone on this list https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors or https://civicrm.org/work-with-the-core-team. There is also a fundraising process you can initiate - see https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Make+it+Happen.

Comment: I understand the free/contributions part, but seriously, how can any organisation be using it without record locking?

There is immediate data loss without check or warning.   How can this be acceptable anywhere?   How are users dealing with this?

Comment: I've updated answer with a partial solution.